# frame grabbing with a callback function in c++. how does it communicate with a class?

Tags: c++, class, callback, friend-function

I recently bought a GigE camera tha came bundles with its SDK. 
One of the examples explains how to grab frames from the camera through a callback function. It works in the following way:

```
void OnImageGrabbed(Image* pImage, const void* pCallbackData)
{
    printf( "Grabbed image %d\n", imageCnt++ );
    return;
}

//...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    camera.StartCapture(OnImageGrabbed);
}
```

the above is based on a simple cpp program (no objects involved).

Now I am trying to incorporate the functionality in my object oriented application (written in openFrameworks ). 
I am really fuzzy as to how to do that and I haven't been able to find close enough example to follow on the internet.

basically what I do in my `header` file:

```
class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

        friend void OnImageGrabbed(Image* pImage, const void* pCallbackData);

        bool bNewFrameArrived;
};
```

then in my `implementation` (.cpp) file

```
void ofApp::setup()
{
    bNewFrame = false ;
    cam.StartCapture(OnImageGrabbed);
}

void OnImageGrabbed(Image* pImage, const void* pCallbackData)
{
    bNewFrame = false ;
    cout<< "Grabbed image" << endl;

    bNewFrame = true ;
}

void ofApp::update(){
    //somehow grab the pImage. but how???

    if ( bNewFrame ) 
        //do stuff
}
```

having this as a friend class is fine, but how can I access the instantiation of the `ofApp` class (namely the bNewFrame variable)? Also how can I access `pImage` afterwards from my `update()` member function?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the signature for camera.StartCapture()?

Comment: @kpaleniu, I am not sure what the signature is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways, depending on can you use member functions or even lambdas as a callback. If it is a C-style function pointer, then options are slightly limited.

Firstly, you could add a static `std::deque` or `std::vector` to file scope, where callback pushes the image pointers. After that, process whatever `Image` pointers the queue/vector holds. See the following.

```
static std::vector<Image*> s_imageQueue;
....

void onImageGrabbed(Image* image, const void* callbackData)
{
    s_imageQueue.push_back(image);
}
...

void ofApp::update()
{
    ...
    for (auto image : s_imageQueue)
    {
        // process image
    }
    s_imageQueue.clear();
    ...
}
```

If `camera.StartCapture()` accepts `std::function<void(Image*,const void*)>`, you could just do something like the following.

```
void ofApp::setup()
{
    camera.StartCamera( [] (Image* image, const void* data) {
        // process image here
    });
}
```

Comment: the 1st way definitely works. shouldn't `s_imageQueue` be a member of the `ofApp` class though? If yes, how could I go about it using it in the friend function `OnGrabbedImage()` ?